# Use a Custom CakeResponse Class in CakePHP 2.1+

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to use a Custom `CakeResponse` class however none of my current work nor current searches have led me to a solution towards actually using one.

So let's call my custom `CakeResponse` class `AppResponse`:

`AppResponse` is in `Lib/Network`

```
<?php
App::uses('CakeResponse', 'Network');

class AppResponse extends CakeResponse {
}
```

Based on this blog post http://mark-story.com/posts/view/cakeresponse-in-cakephp-2-0 it appears that one should be able to use this code to override the CakeResponse and use the custom Response class

```
App::import('Lib', 'CustomResponse');

class AppController extends Controller {
    protected $_responseClass = 'CustomResponse';
}
```

The below collection of `App::uses/import` statements does not work

```
App::uses('AppResponse', 'Network');
App::uses('AppResponse', 'Lib/Network');
App::uses('AppResponse', 'Lib');
App::import('Lib', 'AppResponse');

class AppController extends Controller {

    protected $_responseClass = 'AppResponse';
}

public function beforeRender() {
    debug($this->_responseClass);
    debug(get_class($this->response));
    die();
}
```

This will output:

`AppResponse`
`CakeResponse`

The Book and [CakePHP docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-CakeResponse.html) do seem to suggest it is possible to overwrite a CakeResponse class and use your own custom one.

As evidenced by the above, it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Before you do that **why** do you think you need to do that? I'm pretty sure there are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this is to edit the `webroot/index.php` file and change the Response Class used to your new custom CakeResponse Class.

Solution:

```
App::uses('AppResponse', 'Lib/Network');

$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(
    new CakeRequest(),
    new AppResponse()
);
```

Note: Credit for this solution [is a tweet from Mark Story](https://twitter.com/mark_story/status/566202585141747713).